# How to get account details in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi guys I'm developing a app in flutter. I need to get the gmail accounts that are logged in my device.  But I couldn't get any package related to that.while researching I got account picker package.but account picker is not I want. What I need is to get all the accounts that are logged in my device.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to make a module social login using Google account. You can use [google_sign_in](https://pub.dev/packages/google_sign_in) package (along with Firebase as description). This package allows you to receive an Google access token as long as other information like email address, avatar, name...

However, your question could be understood in different meaning, you want to access ALL logged account in device. That's impossible, these are very sensitive information with strong protection and secure. Those **cannot** be accessed via any mobile application, except system level.

Comment: Tq for the information what I need is to access all logged account in device.but now I came to an conclusion that is not possible